# YARN: what subsystem connecting to port 44874

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run my MR job on YARN. There is this error in one of the userlogs on the node3:

```
2014-10-10 00:57:16,965 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Executing with tokens:
2014-10-10 00:57:16,965 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1412895371072_0001, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@69d5af30)
2014-10-10 00:57:17,330 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Sleeping for 0ms before retrying again. Got null now.
2014-10-10 00:57:18,547 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node03/127.0.1.1:44874. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-10-10 00:57:19,548 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node03/127.0.1.1:44874. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...
2014-10-10 00:57:27,558 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node03/127.0.1.1:44874. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-10-10 00:57:27,562 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.net.ConnectException: Call From node03/127.0.1.1 to node03:44874 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:231)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getTask(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:137)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:367)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1463)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1382)
        ... 4 more

2014-10-10 00:57:27,564 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping MapTask metrics system...
2014-10-10 00:57:27,566 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: MapTask metrics system stopped.
:
```

I have the same config on all nodes. I can't find anywhere having specified port 44874. What does this error actually telling?

Answer (score 2):

If by "half-random" you mean completely random and by "can't really be configured" you mean undocumented and completely f'ed when used in a hardened environmment - you are correct.

The problem is that map-reduce jobs are using dynamic ports. Horton of course doesn't document why the random port is being created.

The answer thus far: disable firewall or allow high ranges (32768-65535) to on each data node. I am still looking for why this situation occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see a problem with Hadoop's ports, I google the port number and see if it is a default port for something. In your case it doesn't seem to be.

As far as I can tell, Hadoop uses this kind of half-random ports internally for some things and they can't be really configured. If there is a problem with this kind of ports, for me it has always been an indication of some other (detectable) problem.

I suggest you go through all your logs again to find other problems. Also check namenode statuses (web interface) and make sure all connections are working.